# Solaris awk Troubles

Tags: awk, solaris, nawk

I'm writing a shell script and I need to strip FIND ME out of something like this:

```
* *[**FIND ME**](find me)*&#x0d;
```

and assign it to an array.  I had the code working flawlessly .. until I moved the script in Solaris to a non-global zone.  Here is the code I used before:

```
objectArray[$i]=`echo $line | nawk -F '*[**|**]' '{print $2}'`
```

Now Prints:

```
awk: syntax error near line 1  
awk: bailing out near line 1
```

It was suggested that I try the same command with nawk, but I receive this error now instead:

```
nawk: illegal primary in regular expression `* *[**|**]` at  `*[**|**]`
 input record number 1
 source line number 1
```

Also, `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk` does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to be clearer on what you want to get. For me your awk line doesn't 'strip FIND ME out'

```
echo "* *[**FIND ME**](find me)*" | nawk -F '* *[**|**]' '{print $2}'
[
```

So it would help if you gave some examples of the input/output you are expecting. Maybe there's a way to do what you want with `sed`?

EDIT:

From comments you actually want to select "FIND ME" from line, not strip it out.

I guess the dialect of regular expressions accepted by this `nawk` is different than `gawk`. So maybe a tool that's better suited to the job is in order.

```
echo "* *[**FIND ME**](find me)*" | sed -e"s/.*\* \*\[\*\*\(.[^*]*\)\*\*\].*/\1/"
FIND ME
```

Comment: It worked for me with awk, I have not successfully tested the nawk output.  Here's what I want:

I know that $line=* *[**FIND_ME**](find_me)*&#x0d;

and I want to assign objectArray[$i]=FIND_ME

Sed might work, I will give this a try.

Comment: So you actually want to select "FIND_ME" from such lines?

Comment: Sorry, Try This:  
echo "* *[**FIND_ME**](find_me)*" | awk -F '*[**|**]' '{print $2}'

Comment: Yes, I want to select FIND_ME.

Answer (score 1):

quote your `$line` variable like this: `"$line"`. If still doesn't work,  you can do it another way  with nawk, since you only want to find one instance of FIND ME,

```
$ echo "$line" | nawk '{gsub(/.*\*\[\*\*|\*\*\].*/,"");print}'
FIND ME
```

or if you are using bash/ksh on Solaris,

```
$ line="${line#*\[\*\*}"
$ echo "${line%%\*\*\]*}"
FIND ME
```

Comment: The shell-only solution should also work with ksh, which should be on Solaris

Comment: Ought to use double quotes: `line="${line#*[\*\*}"; echo "${line%%\*\*]*}"`

Comment: Hmm, need more backslashes here too: `line="${line#*\[\\*\\*}"; echo "${line%%\\*\\*\]*}"`

Comment: what shell did you use? I have no problem with my bash shell. However, i will just edit it.